# Crystal Report CSV export adding blank cells and unable to add quotes to numbers

Tags: csv, crystal-reports, export-to-csv

A client has requested a specific CSV format for their report. When exported to CSV, blank cells are being added to the group header.

The comma's in the dollar values are also being seen as delimiter, so I need to figure out a way to add quotes around them. I have tried ToText, but the formula check keeps stating that the remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula.

[image]

**Here is the formula**

```
if{bnkacrpt.trans_type}<>"OB"
    then if {bnkacrpt.amount} > 0
        then {bnkacrpt.amount}
            else if {bnkacrpt.amount} < 0
            then ({bnkacrpt.amount} * -1)
    else 0    
else 0
```

**The layout** (This is the only active component in the report):
[image]

**The export options:**

[image]

**The result:**

[image]

**What they want:**

[image]

I have tried many different variations on the export options, but am having no luck. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't a complete answer, I would comment if I could.

Totext needs parenthesis around the text you're converting. 
Try this to at least get the formula working.

```
if {bnkacrpt.trans_type} <> "OB"
  then if {bnkacrpt.amount} > 0
    then ToText({bnkacrpt.amount})
  else if {bnkacrpt.amount} < 0 
    then ToText({bnkacrpt.amount} * -1)
  else ToText(0)
else ToText(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but when I do that, it simply states " A String is Required Here" and highlights the 'if' in the 'else if' on the next line. It's OK, I'll wing it and see how I go. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

OK. So I had to basically hack the living daylights out of it and just *make* it work.

Formula (there is another formula for the description column that I did similar stuff to):

```
stringVar amount := totext({bnkacrpt.amount});
stringVar lessamount := totext({bnkacrpt.amount} * -1);

if{bnkacrpt.trans_type}<>"OB"
    then if amount > totext(0)
        then '"'+amount+'",'
            else if amount < totext(0)
            then '"'+lessamount+'",'
    else totext(0)+','    
else totext(0)+',';
```

In the Layout as shown in my original post, I added a single comma to the blank fields in between the data fields on the description line.

The export options:

[image]

The result:

[image]

I just need to figure out how to get rid of the empty line on top and add empty lines in between the results.

So. Close. 
I also hate this client very much now.

**EDIT**

Finally got it right! Well, from my point of view anyways.
To add the blank lines between the details results, and under the headers line, I added a formula only with "ChrW(13)" in it and put it at the end of both lines.

[image]

/*****************************************/

[image]

To remove the most annoying blank line at the top of the resulting CSV file, I went through all the headers that were suppressed above using the section expert and ticked "Hide", 'Suppress' and Suppress blank section. Not sure which was the culprit, or it could have been all of them, but it works, so I don't care :)